# phantomjs missing cookies, compared with firebug?

Tags: cookies, firebug, phantomjs

i am trying to get cookies using phantomjs, but it appears to be incomplete?

at command line:

```
phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt --debug=true test.js
```

test.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {
   page.evaluate(function() {
      document.cookie;
   });
   page.cookies;
   phantom.cookies;
});
```

i compare cookies.txt with firebug cookies and LiveHttpHeaders, and see there are some cookies missing in the phantomjs saved file?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?